# Watch specific file changes using webpack

Tags: webpack, less, antd

Currently I use less-loader along with `modifyVars` to overwrite some less variables in order to customize the styling.

```
import theme from './theme.js';

{
    test: /\.(css|less)$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss', `less-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"modifyVars":${JSON.stringify(theme)}}`],
}
```

but for every change in `theme.js` I have to restart the server, (doing npm run ) is there a way to make it automatically just like if I change a less file and it will replaced immediately?

theme.js

```
module.exports = {
  '@primary-color': '#1DA57A',
  '@font-size-base': '14px',
  '@btn-font-weight': '200',
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The theme is not a file webpack watches and packs. It is part of the webpack *config*. So the answer is no, you can't make webpack watch it.

You can, however, make someone else watch it and restart webpack. As described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/440#issuecomment-205757892), for example.